# Error de script common.js aleatorio al cargar mapa Gmap en un Web Browser de .NET

Tags: vb.net, .net, windows-forms, google-maps, navegador-web

Detallo el escenario para intentar localizar una solución.

Tengo una aplicación Windows que utiliza dos **webbrowser** embebidos de .NET que cargan respectivos mapas de **Google Map** y sus marcadores correspondientes.

La operativa de carga de los marcadores se hace desde vb.net generando el código de script correspondiente que se manda al control webbrowser que actualiza su visualizacion.

Todo ok y la operativa funciona correctamente, pero de vez en cuando se lanza un error de script que presento en la captura de pantalla y no encuentro información al respecto en Google, ninguna referencia a ese error.

Me temo que se produce en el momento de la carga del API de gmap pero no consigo detectar el problema.

En la imagen, el mapa de la derecha carga los marcadores, pero lanza el error y luego se muestra el mapa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan dar alguna pista. 
Gracias.

Comment: Hola, échale un vistazo a [esta respuesta de S.O. en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604353/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-google-map-javascript-problems) quizás sea la solución

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, ya la habia aplicado anteriormente para otro error que se solucionó pero no para este.